# Coludn't find the following dependencies: com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1 and com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1

Tags: maven-2, maven, pom.xml

i am using maven 2 and i was not able to find the following dependencies:

```
com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1 
com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1
commons-logging: commons-logging:jar:1.1.0.jboss
hibernate-commons-annotations:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.0.0.GA
hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.2
```

i am using following repos in my pom file:

```
<repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <name>jboss</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>javanet</id>
            <name>Repository for Maven2</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>google</id>
            <name>Google repository for Maven2</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-releases/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Library Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Library Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external</url>
        </repository>
```

please tell me if one of them is not good and should be removed, and if i should add another repos to find the missing dependencies, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sun jars I believe you have to download them (from Oracle) and install them in your local repository (licensing issues mean others can't redistribute them in a maven repo)

For the rest, you should find them in the jboss repo

https://repository.jboss.org/

Edit: that version of commons-logging seems to be in a slightly different location:

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/

So you'll have to add that one too

Comment: thanks i will try that, any ideas about the use of the first two sun dependencies ? i couldn't find them in the pom file, i think they are downloaded as part of another dependency.

Comment: That's likely. You can download them from oracle, then you need to install them in your local repo - instructions here http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Alternatively you can just exlude them (since the chances are you're not using them) see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310633/maven-dependency-log4j-error